# How to resize product image of grid page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I beginner to magento2 and list view image is looks fine but not in grid view so i want to resize grid view product image only. please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy **view.xml** file from vendor to your theme and update image size in `category_page_grid`

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Your_Theme/etc/view.xml
```

Search code like below and I hope it will work for you:

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>260</height>
        </image>
```

Comment: yes its worked for me.thank you.